# How to execute slickNext method in react-slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I have the following React app with a Slick carousel. I created a custom Next button and need to execute the `slickNext()` method to proceed to the next slide. The Slick carousel docs and some of the answers for questions have mentioned the following way to call `slickNext()` method.

**The problem is I'm getting the error** `slider.slick is not a function`.

This is what I have tried so far

```
gotoNext = () => {
    var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("sliderMain")[0];
    console.log("set", slider)
    slider.slick("slickNext");
}

const SampleNextArrow = (props) => {
        const { className, style } = props;
        return (
            <div
                className={className}
                onClick={this.gotoNext}
            />
           );
        }

    const settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        swipe: false,
        nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow className="customSlickNext" />,
    };

    <Slider
       id="sliderMain"
       {...settings}
       className="sliderMain"
       afterChange={this.changeSlide}
    >{ /* slider goes here */}
    </Slider>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: why do you have some code after `return` statement?

Comment: @Saeid-a That's my custom arrow div

Comment: You may want to look in the react-slick docs instead, as the method calls are performed differently: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With react-slick, you can add a `ref` prop on `<Slider>`. If you're using hooks, you can do that with `useRef()`:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

...

const sliderRef = useRef();

<Slider
    ref={sliderRef}
    ...
>
</Slider>
```

You can then use `sliderRef` to call Slick methods in your function:

```js
gotoNext = () => {
    sliderRef.current.slickNext();
}
```

The available methods for react-slick can be found at: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#methods

Comment: Thank you. I'm using a class component. So, React.createRef(); worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I have solution when we have `slider` in one component and custom methods  `slickNext()`, `slickPrev()` in other component.

we can't send `ref` as prop. we should use `forwardRef`

in react-slick, you can use  `forwardRef()` on `<Slider>`.

```js
 //carousel.js(child)
    import React, { useRef } from 'react';


    const Carousel = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {


    <Slider
        ref={ref}
        ...
    >
    </Slider>

    })
```

now you can access `ref` in parent component

```js
import Carousel from "./carousel";

let sliderRef = React.useRef();


<a onClick={()=>sliderRef?.current?.slickNext()}>Next</a>
<a onClick={()=>sliderRef?.current?.slickPrev()}>Prev</a>
  
  
<Carousel ref={sliderRef}></Carousel>
```